# Scratch Orgs deployments are incredibly slow lately

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

For a past few days having trouble deploying with `sfdx force:source:push` having troubles with deployments being in `Pending` in 20+ minutes sometimes (I think it mostly concerns newly created orgs).

Have anyone encountered similar issues lately?

P.S. cli is running 7.101.0

Comment: Not seen a consistent slow down. Performance varies from operation to operation as always. I wonder if it is the instance your scratch orgs are being created on?